# Has Palo Alto firewalls released perimeter protection for the vulnerability in the Bash shell utility?

Tags: firewalls, vulnerability, bash

im wondering if palo alto firewalls have released perimeter protection for the bash shell vulnerability.

Comment: Let me Google that for you: http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2014/09/addressing-bash-vulnerability-shellshock-palo-alto-networks-mitigation-cve-2014-6271/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shellshock has been exciting today!

To answer your question: Normal PAN-OS maintenance release updates will provide a fix for the vulnerability. I'd always recommend their wildfire professional subscription on the perimeter, it has worked well for my organization!

But you don't really need it, Palo Alto Networks released an emergency IPS signature for protection against this vulnerability, with *content version 457* on Wednesday evening. Shellshock was leaked (http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/650) with identifier **CVE-2014-6271** They, Palo Alto, intends to release additional IPS coverage for the related **CVE-2014-7219** vulnerability with a second emergency content release sometime within the next 24 hours. Stay Tuned and Stay Safe!

Comment: You can also see more information at https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/

Comment: [Shellshock was not leaked prematurely. It just sounded that way due to somewhat confusing wording.](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/666)

Comment: interesting read - I've edited my response, thanks!